# Text not printing at the end of my for loop for a polyalphabetic cypher

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a polyalphabetic cypher. My code is running, but it is not printing the "cyphertext" at the end. I even tried testing individual parts of the for loop and none of it will print either.

```
import string

alpha = string.ascii_lowercase

message = input('Message:')
message = message.upper()

secretWord = input('Secret word:')
secretWord = secretWord.upper()

cypherText = ''

count = 0
for letter in message:
  if letter in alpha:
    shift = alpha.index(secretWord[count])
    letterIndex = alpha.index(letter)
    cypherLetter = alpha[(letterIndex+shift)%26]
    cypherText = cypherText + cypherLetter
count = count+1

print(cypherText)
```

Comment: You are converting the message to `upper()` case but then comparing to `ascii_lowercase` - so `if letter in alpha` is always `False`. You have a similar issue with `secretWord`. Use `message.lower()` and `secretWord.lower()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your *message* is in upper case but *alpha* is in lower so *letter* from your iteration over *message* will never be in *alpha*

You are also increasing *count* outside your loop which result in a constant *shift*

Answer (score 1):

You are making every character uppercase and then you are checking to see if it is a lower case character. As the upper case character isn't a lower case character it doesn't get encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Use upper or lower case everywhere in your code:

```
import string

alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
message = input('Message: ').lower()
secret_word = input('Secret word: ').lower()
cypher_text = ''
for i, letter in enumerate(message):
    if letter in alpha:
        shift = alpha.index(secret_word[i]) if len(secret_word) > i else alpha.index(secret_word[0])
        letter_index = alpha.index(letter)
        cypher_letter = alpha[(letter_index + shift) % 26]
        cypher_text = cypher_text + cypher_letter
print(cypher_text)
```

Output:

```
Message: animal
Secret word: snake
saiwed
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into pycharm and it says: line 9, in <module>
    shift = alpha.index(secret_word[i])
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: What are your inputs for `message` and `secret_word`?

Comment: "animal" and "snake"